# Mercurial - which head is active in your working directory?

Tags: mercurial

`hg head` lists multiple heads.  How do you know which head is active in your working directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hg id` gives you the revision of the working directory. `hg sum` provides the same information and some more. You might also want to check the [compass extension](https://bitbucket.org/obensonne/hg-compass/wiki/Home) which provides detailed information about the "location" of your working copy within the whole repository.

Comment: hg summary is what we usually recommend here.

Answer (score 0):

From the command line, you can use: `hg log -r .` to see the revision of your working copy.